# How do you implement a login warning banner in Gnome 3?

Tags: fedora, login, gnome3

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/79522/how-do-you-implement-a-warning-banner-in-fedora) documents how we used to inflict the mandatory login banners required on our Linux machines at work. Unfortunately, this procedure is no longer effective with Gnome 3 in Fedora 15, 16 or 17. Gnome 3 seems to ignore the banner_message fields in gconf-editor.

Does Gnome 3 provide an equivalent procedure that allows us to present a warning message to users prior to login?

Comment: [Seems like it's being worked on...(`bugzilla.gnome.org`)](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=665346)

Comment: @sr_, I see that bugzilla entry but I see no evidence that that patch will ever make it into anything.  There's been another major release of Fedora since that bug was updated.

Answer (score 1):

For the people still wondering how to implement a banner at login time I did this:

## For Fedora

- Create a file 20-login in /etc/dconf/db/local.d/: `touch /etc/dconf/db/local.d/20-login`
- Put the following configuration in that file

  `[org/gnome/login-screen]
  banner-message-enable=true
  banner-message-text='My warning banner!'`
- Delete /etc/dconf/db/local: `rm -f /etc/dconf/db/local`
- Update dconf: `dconf update`

## For Ubuntu

Uncomment the following lines in `/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults` and edit the `banner-message-text`

- `[org/gnome/login-screen]`
- `banner-message-enable=true`
- `banner-message-text='Welcome!'`

Then restart gdm `systemctl restart gdm`