# How can I disable the user list login screen in Gnome 3 on Fedora 16 or 17?

Tags: fedora, login, gnome3, gdm

Our login screen requirements include a [warning / disclaimer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38420/how-do-you-implement-a-login-warning-banner-in-gnome-3) and a basic login, showing just a username and password field.  Sadly, Gnome 3 seems to be ignoring the `org.gnome.login-screen.disable-user-list` checkbox presented by `dconf-editor`.

Can you disable the list of users displayed prior to login in Gnome 3 GDM?

Comment: For `gdm3` see: [How to disable the user list on GDM3 login screen?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205058)

Answer (score 5):

gdm3 loads its configuration in its own dconf database. This is separate apparently from the user dconf db that is accessible from the GUI with dconf-editor.

To edit the key value pairs which control the gdm settings and the login screen create a custom file in the /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d and add the custom entries there.

Do the following as the root user:

1. touch /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/01-custom-gdm-settings
2. Add the following:

   [org/gnome/login-screen]

   disable-user-list=true
3. Update the dconf database

   dconf update
4. Restart gdm.

   systemctl restart gdm

   or

   /etc/init.d/gdm restart

More details on this can be found on the gnome sysadmin FAQ.

https://live.gnome.org/SysAdminGuide

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me (Oracle Linux 6.5)
http://blog.toracat.org/2011/01/gnome-login-shows-all-valid-user-accounts-disable-it/

Edit the `/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults/%gconf-tree.xml` file

Under this section

```
<entry name="disable_user_list" mtime="1400746800" type="schema" stype="bool" owner="gdm-simple-greeter" gettext_domain="gdm"
   <local_schema locale="C" short_desc="Do not show known users in the login window">
      <default type="bool" value="false"/>
      <longdesc>Set to true to disable showing known users in the login window.</longdesc>
   </local_schema>
</entry>
```

Change `false` to `true` and logout.